# Java 7 Checked exception rules

Tags: java, java-7, unhandled-exception

I know the rules about checked exceptions, but I can't quite work out this puzzler.  Why does thfe second method not compile, but the first one does?  The error is "Unhandled exception type Exception" on the last throws statement.  I can understand why I get this error, but I don't understand why the first method is ok, it should have the same problem?!

Both eclipse and intellij show the same error.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class ThrowableWeirdness {

    public void doWithMetrics(String name, Runnable runnable) {

        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.printf(name + ".failed");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public <RET> RET doWithMetrics(String name, Callable<RET> runnable) {

        try {
            return runnable.call();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.printf(name + ".failed");
            throw e; // Compilation error on this line: unhandled exception
        }
    }
}
```

Can you explain the difference between the two methods?

Comment: The first method does not compile neither on my Eclipse... You're sure you did not forget some `throws Throwable` in your methods signatures?

Comment: yep, same here, both method give out unhanded exception error.

Comment: Strange.  I'm using java 7, maybe that makes a difference.  The first method definate compiles, and also runs!

Comment: Java 7 changes are part of project coin, and I've found an explanation of the change: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the first case, `runnable.run` does not throw any checked `Exception`, so your `try`/`catch` and rethrow are not inferred to throw anything checked, hence it compiles
- In your second case, `runnable.call()` throws `Exception` and is handled, but then rethrown.

In order to fix the compilation in this case, you **must** add a `throws` statement to your method declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  It's just that in java 6 neither method would compile, but in java 7 there is a fix for rethrowing exceptions. I think I'll move to a guava Function instead of Callable.

Comment: @DavidRoussel yes, rethrowing behavior differs between 6 and 7. I'm not familiar with Guava, but I'd find it a bit weird to require using an external framework just for that rethrowing behavior change...

Comment: Actually in the end I defined a new interface for my purpose.  I wanted something like callable, but without a checked exception. I'm not a checked exception fan.

Answer (score 2):

From Java 7 Onward, the compiler inspect the try block to check [what exception are actually going to be raised](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html):

> However, in Java SE 7, you can specify the exception types
>   FirstException and SecondException in the throws clause in the
>   rethrowException method declaration. The Java SE 7 compiler can
>   determine that the exception thrown by the statement throw e must have
>   come from the try block, and the only exceptions thrown by the try
>   block can be FirstException and SecondException. Even though the
>   exception parameter of the catch clause, e, is type Exception, the
>   compiler can determine that it is an instance of either FirstException
>   or SecondException

if you set source level to 1.6, both of them won't compile.